# sharepoint designer 2013 workflow stuck in progress

Tags: 2013, designer

I created a list for internal approval and a workflow to perform this approval.
I have designed a workflow below that is simple one. The workflow initate the action well - Set the pending status, send an email to assign the task.

[image]

The one who received the task can access to it as you can see below

[image]

For Taks Status: I have removed the all default status and set 2 (Not started and Completed). when the screen is open the default status = blank

For Task Outcome, I have removed the default one, and set Need more info/Rejected/Compliance Notified. When the contact takes action and select for example

- Task Status = Completed
- Task Outcome = Compliance Notified

When clicked in Save, normally an email will autogenerated and inform about the status. But this is not happened here.

As you can see in the screen below, the status of workflow stuck at stage name "Pending to review" and I think that the email notification was not sent, due to this status.

Can you help me here and tell me what wrong with my workflow?

[image]

Thanks in advance for your support.

rgs

Frederic

Comment: Does the workflow run on item created and item editing both?

Comment: Harshal gite
the wkf run for item created and inform creator about the creation and approval contact about a new entry should be approved... but the workflow stop here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your workflow actually completed without going where you anticipated. To me, it looks like your if-conditions weren't being satisfied and it ignored them. Double check your spelling and that the output in `Request Status` is actually just a word and not an indexed value like `0;Rejected` or something.

Some logging comments like `Entered Stage: Pending for review`, `value of the variable "TaskID" is: xx`, and `Entered if-condition Rejected` could be useful to verify your workflow hits what you want it to.

I'd also suggest cleaning up the conditions a bit. I've done a quick review of your workflow that goes over the duplicate code.

[image]

In your transition in the first stage there, if the `Total Support Services` isn't `less than or equal to` 999, then it has to be `greater than or equal to` 1000, assuming integer values. That means that it'll always go to the Pending for Review stage, and won't ever end the workflow.

In `Stage: Pending for Review` you change the status to what you had in `Stage: Stage 2` (no change, realistically), then enter the always true statement (can't get to this stage without it being true already), and change status to what you just changed it to... again.

Similar concept for `Stage: Pending for Review 2`

Comment: Thanks KGlasier. I have fixed the issue and the wkf works.
thanks a lot

Comment: If my solution worked for you, feel free to mark my solution as correct (checkmark to the left) so that others know this worked.